# post input correctly from 2D array of input type=checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an 2D array of form, method=POST, where I want to get the days on which a subject have classes using input type=checkbox.

```
<input type='text' name='subject[]' />
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='monday[]' value='M'>M</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='tuesday[]' value='T'>T</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='wednesday[]' value='W'>W</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='thursday[]' value='Th'>Th</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='friday[]' value='F'>F</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='saturday[]' value='Sa'>Sa</label>
<input type='text' name='subject[]' />
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='monday[]' value='M'>M</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='tuesday[]' value='T'>T</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='wednesday[]' value='W'>W</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='thursday[]' value='Th'>Th</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='friday[]' value='F'>F</label>
<label> <input type='checkbox' name='saturday[]' value='Sa'>Sa</label>
```

and with the following inputs (2 rows):
{Subject1, M}
{Subject2 T, W}
I am expecting that PHP will fetch the $_POST variable as:

```
  'subject' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Subject1' (length=8)
      1 => string 'Subject2' (length=8)
  'monday' => 
    array (size=1)
      **1 => string 'M' (length=1)**
  'tuesday' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'T' (length=1)
  'wednesday' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'W' (length=1)
```

^result from var_dump($_POST); but it fetch it as:

```
'subject' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Subject1' (length=8)
      1 => string 'Subject2' (length=8)
  'monday' => 
    array (size=1)
      **0 => string 'M' (length=1)**
  'tuesday' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'T' (length=1)
  'wednesday' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'W' (length=1)
```

what should I do to fetch the values correctly?

Comment: Why did you name all the checkboxes different?

Comment: Y not use one array for all the days like `<input type='checkbox' name='days[]' value='M'>M</label>` ???

Comment: if i use `name='days[]'` it results into ` 'days' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'M' (length=1)
      1 => string 'T' (length=1)
      2 => string 'W' (length=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Change all `checkbox` name as `days[]` and in your php file use this code `$_POST['days']`. this will returns all selected values.

Comment: that will return the values as ` 'days' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'M' (length=1)
      1 => string 'T' (length=1)
      2 => string 'W' (length=1)` but the code snippet is only for one row. but the code is for 2D array of forms

Comment: use this `print_r($_POST['days'])`. `vardump` shows value and its datatype http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php.